# ¿Recorrer array con foreach y con los valores obtenidos mapear otro array?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el array "concept" del cual me interesa obtener los valores del campo l_prod, y dicho valores pasarlos a la función map a mi otro array "datos".

Lo he tratado de realizarlo de la siguiente manera, pero no me funciona... espero he halla dejado entender y me puedan ayudar, de antemano gracias.

```js
  const concept = [{"c_prod":"000004","l_prod":"FAENAS"},
              {"c_prod":"000005","l_prod":"MULTAS"}];
  const datos = [
      {"n_docu":"23248169","l_agen":"USUARIO","FAENAS":"1.00","MULTAS":"0.00"},
      {"n_docu":"71377558","l_agen":"SIMEON","FAENAS":"5.00","MULTAS":"1.00"}, 
      {"n_docu":"46117631","l_agen":"EGUAVIL","FAENAS":"0.00","MULTAS":"1.00"}
  ];
  var resp = [];
  concept.forEach(function(c,i) {
     var l_prod = c.l_prod; 
     resp.push(datos.map(d => d.l_prod));
  });
  console.log(resp);
```

RESULTADO QUE DESEO OBTENER

```
 [ ["1.00", "5.00", "0.00"],["0.00", "1.00", "1.00"]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que no se puede usar *dot notation* el valor de una variable.

La instrucción `d.l_prod` está retornando literalmente el valor de la clave `"l_prod"` del objeto `d`. Como `d` no tiene esa clave, devuelve `undefined`.

Para conseguir lo que necesitas debes hacerlo con la siguiente sintaxis

```
const l_prod = c.l_prod;
const value = d[l_prod];
```

De este modo logras lo que quieres, acceder a la clave `"FAENAS"` o `"MULTAS"` o cualquier valor que `l_prod` pueda tener.

Adicionalmente, puedes simplificar la solución usando dos `map`.
Te dejo el ejemplo completo.

```js
const concepts = [
  {c_prod:"000004",l_prod:"FAENAS"},
  {c_prod:"000005",l_prod:"MULTAS"}
];

const datos = [
  {n_docu:"23248169",l_agen:"USUARIO",FAENAS:"1.00",MULTAS:"0.00"},
  {n_docu:"71377558",l_agen:"SIMEON",FAENAS:"5.00",MULTAS:"1.00"}, 
  {n_docu:"46117631",l_agen:"EGUAVIL",FAENAS:"0.00",MULTAS:"1.00"}
];

const result = concepts.map(
  ({ l_prod }) => datos.map(d => d[l_prod])
);

console.log(result);
// [["1.00", "5.00", "0.00"], ["0.00", "1.00", "1.00"]]
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta! Explicas de forma sencilla el error y cómo acceder a las propiedades. +1